# core data - cannot find data for a temporary oid in mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification

Tags: core-data

Occasionally I'm getting temporary oid failures while merging contexts in my app. Here is the code. I can't reproduce this bug while testing, it only seems to happen out in the wild.

```
- (void)didSave:(NSNotification *)note
{
    if (((NSManagedObjectContext *)note.object).persistentStoreCoordinator != [self managedObjectContext].persistentStoreCoordinator)
        return;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // fails on the next line
        [[self managedObjectContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:note];
        ...
    });
}
```

randomly gives me this:

> cannot find data for a temporary oid: 0x1464d6b0 <\x-coredata://52C9DDE6-A4F8-4BD7-B9B8-7D59F3876D74/ContactSet/tA3AF19CB-90CD-4610-A15E-33A2821B1AF1220>

Should I be checking the notification type?

(note the concurrency type is set to main thread)

Comment: What notifications are registered to call this method?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html